# Remove event listener javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently doing a simple rock, paper, scissors game with javascript however, removeEventListener() doesn't seem to be working in my code. I know I used a loop to apply the event listeners to the buttons, so I will figure out the loop to remove them later.

For now, I don't understand why my code won't remove the event listener on the button that's clicked:

```
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');

btns.forEach(function(item) {

    item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        results.textContent = '';
        playRound(event.target.className, getComputerChoice());
        
        if (playerCount == 5) {
            item.removeEventListener('click', event);
            winner.textContent = `YOU WON 5 GAMES!`;

        }else if (cpuCount == 5) {
            item.removeEventListener('click', event);
            winner.textContent = `YOU LOSE! CPU WINS 5`;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Mina's answer answers your question. However, I wonder what is the purpose of of removing the listener in the first place. If you don't want the user to continue playing after 5 wins/loses you can simply have an IF statement in the click handler that doesn't allow anything to happen if 5 wins/loses happened.

Comment: @imvain2 True, however, this is more of trying to understand adding and removing event listeners.

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#parameters) took is the `addEventListner` callback function, so I suggest you to separate the `addEventListner` callback to a named function and use it in both `addEventListner` and `removeEventListner`

```
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function onClickHandler(event) {
        results.textContent = '';
        playRound(event.target.className, getComputerChoice());
        
        if (playerCount == 5) {
            item.removeEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
            winner.textContent = `YOU WON 5 GAMES!`;

        }else if (cpuCount == 5) {
            item.removeEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
            winner.textContent = `YOU LOSE! CPU WINS 5`;
        }
    });
}

btns.forEach(function(item) {

    item.addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest or ***best*** answer to this would probably be the one posted by **Mina**, however I am posting this answer as another valid alternative for those who are looking into similar issues.

While you can declare an actual callback function that can be easily added and removed to/from an event listener, you can also pull in an anonymous callback function by passing in `...args` to your callback function as well. Once `...args` is passed in and exists, you can use `args.callee` as the callback function for `removeEventListener()` to remove the current anonymous function from an element.

I should also note that `...args` specifically applies to arrow functions. A more *classic* `function(event) {` setup like the one posted by OP can use an `arguments` variable that exists for those types of functions. Arrow functions require you to also pass in `...args` to obtain additional argument values.

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');

btns.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e, ...args) => {
    results.textContent = '';
    playRound(e.target.className, getComputerChoice());
    
    if(playerCount == 5) {
      item.removeEventListener('click', args.callee);
      winner.textContent = `YOU WON 5 GAMES!`;
    } else if(cpuCount == 5) {
      item.removeEventListener('click', args.callee);
      winner.textContent = `YOU LOSE! CPU WINS 5`;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes! I knew I've seen this before, except it was:
```item.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee);